# Processing very large list of dataframes by chunks in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Let's say I have a list of 1000 dataframes:

```
1000_dataframe_list
```

And because of memory problems with spread(), I need to process this list by chunks. To process the whole list, I'm using:
"

```
out_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 1000_dataframe_list)

data_wide <- spread(out_df, Sample, expression)
```

My idea is to process the list in chunks, then merge all chunks. As you can see, data_wide is a basically a matrix with the first column being rownames, but I don't think this matters very much.

How can I process the 1000_dataframe_list in a way that I can divide it by any number of parts I need (10, 100, 200, using this number as input for the number of chunks)?

Comment: FWIW: (1) `tidyr::spread` has been retired/superseded since at least Apr 2019 (commit [17bb14c](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/commit/17bb14c2586b924786512ea1281862186f0c5951)), strongly recommend shifting to `pivot_wider`, which is more feature-full and I suspect faster (untested). (2) I suggest `bind_rows(framelist)` in place of `do.call(rbind.data,frame framelist)`, for many reasons.

Comment: pivot_wider works even for a very large dataset! This code is old (6 years old to be precise), so updating it is great.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::fish_encounters` for sample data, the documentation suggests simply

```r
res1 <- fish_encounters %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = station, values_from = seen)
res1
# # A tibble: 19 × 12
#    fish  Release I80_1 Lisbon  Rstr Base_TD   BCE   BCW  BCE2  BCW2   MAE   MAW
#    <fct>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1 4842        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#  2 4843        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#  3 4844        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#  4 4845        1     1      1     1       1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  5 4847        1     1      1    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  6 4848        1     1      1     1      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  7 4849        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  8 4850        1     1     NA     1       1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  9 4851        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 10 4854        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 11 4855        1     1      1     1       1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 12 4857        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
# 13 4858        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
# 14 4859        1     1      1     1       1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 15 4861        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
# 16 4862        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
# 17 4863        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 18 4864        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 19 4865        1     1      1    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Now, if we split that into a list of frames,

```r
framelist <- fish_encounters %>%
  group_split(g = row_number() %/% 20) %>%
  lapply(select, -g)
length(framelist)
# [1] 6
sapply(framelist, nrow)
# [1] 19 20 20 20 20 15
```

we can get to the same results via chunks:

```r
res2 <- framelist %>%
  lapply(pivot_wider, names_from = "station", values_from = "seen") %>%
  bind_rows()
res2
# # A tibble: 24 × 12
#    fish  Release I80_1 Lisbon  Rstr Base_TD   BCE   BCW  BCE2  BCW2   MAE   MAW
#    <fct>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1 4842        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#  2 4843        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
#  3 4843       NA    NA     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
#  4 4844        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#  5 4845        1     1      1     1       1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  6 4847        1    NA     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  7 4847       NA     1      1    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  8 4848        1     1      1     1      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#  9 4849        1     1     NA    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 10 4850        1     1     NA     1       1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
# # ℹ 14 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Notice, though, that `fish == 4843` is found in two separate chunks so we need a strategy to combine them. In this case, I think it's just `sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE)`, so

```r
res2 %>%
  summarize(
    across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    # because `res1` has `NA` when not seen, not `0`
    across(everything(), ~ if_else(.x == 0, NA, .x)),
    .by = fish
  ) %>%
  all.equal(res1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that this uses `.by=fish`, a feature added in `dplyr_1.1.0`; if you don't have that, use `group_by(fish)` before `summarize(..).

Bottom line:

- pivoting/reshaping by chunk is identical to pivoting/reshaping the whole frame, but you may have to deal with a row being spread across multiple chunks as I've displayed here
- it is feasible (perhaps *likely*) that there may be columns in one chunk that are not present in another; if you try to use `do.call(rbind.data.frame, ..)`, it will complain:

  ```r
  res2a <- framelist %>%
    lapply(pivot_wider, names_from = "station", values_from = "seen")
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, res2a)
  # Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  #   numbers of columns of arguments do not match
  ```

  The use of `bind_rows` remedies this, as it automatically row-binds by-name and fills with `NA` where columns exist in one chunk and not the other.